# Admittance calculation of a circuit

Tags: resistance, inductance, conductivity

[image]I am measuring the admittance of a circuit, by switching a load off and on at different loads. The admittance value I got from the measured voltage drop and current flowing through my circuit. The problem is calculation is only good when the circuit is only resistive or having high power factor (0.9 to 1.0). As soon as the inductive impedance value goes up, the admittance measurement shows discrepancies. Can somebody please throw some light on it?

Comment: what is the circuit? How did you measure? My crystal ball says you need to consider spectrum of admittance vs load and step response affects spectrum.

Comment: Normally averaged over one cycle for repetitive switching with duty cycle, d  then Z(f)'= Z(f)/d fundamental or with spectrum harmonic content of asymmetry for even harmonics then Z(f)=FFT of V(t)/I(t) = 1/S(f). A true voltage source is expected such that Rs/Z(f) <<1% or if you expect max power transfer as Glenn suggests  use conjugate matching

Comment: Sir, Here the resistor R8 is my load and I am measuring the voltage and current across this one. Anytime I connect a new load (in this case R1 to R7), I switch off and on R8 and note down the voltage and current change, (Change in Current)/(change in voltage) gives me my admittance value. But works only till power factor is 0.9 to 1.0, any drop my formula fails !!!

Comment: ΔI/ΔV works in steady state, but during Δt sample interval reactive loads with nonlinear switches with non-ideal components ( R+X(f)) then will be inaccurate unless time constant T is considered.  Consider switching a cap voltage instantly: What controls the current? C or ESR actually it is ΔV/(Rs+ESR) for  switch with Rs.

Comment: @Kunal Who said (complex) admittance is calculated as change in current over change in voltage? It is calculated as (phasor) current over (phasor) voltage. Am I missing something? By the way, can you share the Simulink model?

Comment: Are you doing quadrature measurements? Anytime you use a reactive element, you need to take the phase angle in to consideration. If you are only using peak amplitude values, you will get erroneous measurements if reactive components are involved, however, you will get correct answers for pure resistances.

Answer (score 1):

*The comment button doesn't work, so I write one here. Delete this freely if it's too long or not allowed.*

Inserting a load resistor to a linear circuit and checking what it causes can tell what's the Thevenin (or as well Norton) equivalent of the circuit.

Thevenin voltage (rms only, not the phase angle) can be got by measuring the unloaded voltage with an AC voltmeter. Inserting  load resistor R8 causes some voltage drop. The loaded voltage must satisfy the voltage division equation written as complex phasor formula. The Thevenin equivalent impedance **Zt** must be assumed to have real and imaginary parts **Zt** = Rt + jXt.

The voltage division equation (for rms voltages) reduces to a 2nd degree real number algebraic equation. It has 2 unknowns Rt and Xt. In addition the sign of Xt is ambiguous because Xt occurs only as squared.

You must make a 2nd measurement with different load to get another equation for solving both Rt and Xt. If the new load is reactive you can decide also the sign (capacitive or inductive) of the Xt. But you may know the sign. In that case different R8s can be both resistors.

Believe, solving the pair of 2nd degree equations is a challenge for practically oriented electricians, but solving it numerically with right tools should be easy.

The found Et, Rt and Xt (or equivalent Norton parameters) still do not tell the exact component values of the problematic circuit. If you know exactly the "Pi Section Line" and the fed voltage from the transformer you can solve the total resistance of R1....R7. If you do not know that line or the transformer output voltage you must find them, too. Changing only R8 and measuring the loaded and unloaded output voltage cannot give more than what's the Thevenin equivalent.

Answer (score 0):

Two givens:

- Admittance is the reciprocal of impedance.
- Due to the maximum power theorem, maximum power in the load is
  attained when the load is the conjugate match of the output
  impedance. This means R<sub>source</sub>=R<sub>load</sub> and j<sub>source</sub>=-j<sub>load</sub>

Find the load that draws the maximum power, compute its conjugate (since the source impedance is its conjugate), and take the reciprocal of this conjugate to derive the complex admittance of the circuit's output.

Comment: Sir, I have updated my circuit. Kindly have a look.Here the resistor R8 is my load and I am measuring the voltage and current across this one. Anytime I connect a new load (in this case R1 to R7), I switch off and on R8 and note down the voltage and current change, (Change in Current)/(change in voltage) gives me my admittance value. But works only till power factor is 0.9 to 1.0, any drop my formula fails !!!

Comment: Your switched loads are all resistors. Where is the power factor change coming from?

Comment: From the Pi Section I have connected at the beginning, near the trasnformer!!!, Any increase in inductance shows bad results about admittance.

Comment: If you have inductance in the source impedance, then you must have a capacitive load with equal (but opposite of course) reactance. This is the conjugate load.